# Quantstats (Python library) does not display plot

Tags: python, plot, quantitative-finance

Quantstats is a commonly used library, but I have problems in running examples given its website. The following code is an example from [Quantstats](https://pypi.org/project/QuantStats/) webpage, but it does not display a figure.

```
import quantstats as qt
stock = qt.utils.download_returns('FB')
qt.plots.snapshot(stock)
```

Furthermore, the following code (also an example from Quantstats website) raise an error message "ValueError: `file` must be specified"

```
qt.reports.html(stock, "SPY")
```

For your information, I am running Python in Pycharm.

Any comment and advice would be very much appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

ultados de tradução
Hello @david78.

I had the same error. Reading the project code on github, I found that:

> `if the output is None and not _utils._in_notebook():
>
> > ```
> >     raise ValueError("`file` must be specified")`
> > ```

The _in_notebook() function checks your environment (notebook, command line, etc).

The output parameter determines whether you download a file or not.

I still had some issues with compatibility requirements for plotting on Jupyter or Google Colab notebooks, and with me plotting on notebooks still has a problem.

But, I found that if you include any value in the output parameter, you will get an html file in your local path. For example, I passed output='analytics.html' or output=True and I can get the html report file in my local path.
The final code was:

> qs.reports.html(stock, "SPY", output=True).

In Pycharm you don't have a built-in graph, so the specified output parameter solves your problem.

Comment: Thank you for the help. Adding 'output=True' still does not work for me. However, it works if "download_filename" is added  "qs.reports.html(stock, "SPY", output=True, download_filename='FB.html')"